# Swift Helper class ViewController

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, ads

I have made an iAds and AdMob helper that I designed for my spritekit game that is available on gitHub.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper

The way the helper is designed is that you set a presentingViewController property

```
Ads.sharedInstance.presentingViewController = self
```

once your game launches in your gameViewController (games usually only have 1 viewControlle so it works fine).

However some users have reported that when using the Helper in regular UIKit apps that ads will not show correctly when changing view Controllers.

For UiKit the Ads helper is slightly changed where the helper methods would now look something like this

```
func showBannerAd(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.presentingViewController = viewController
       ....
}
```

and than you can call them in your ViewControllers

```
Ads.sharedInstance.showBannerAd(self)
```

However this still causes issue when changing ViewControllers. I believe it has something to do with the rootViewController.

Can somebody explain how I could use this helper for UIKitApps, mainly how can I use a helper that has a viewControllerProperty

```
 presentingViewController: UIViewController
```

but ensure this property is always the rooViewController so Ads will show regardless of which ViewController is used in the UIKit app.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that I was not calling the rootViewController when presenting ads.

Now I am calling it like so

```
presentingViewController.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentView...
```

which should ensure that ads are always shown even when using multiple view controllers.